# Algebra Fraction Problem - Variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I honestly can't figure out how to get this answer, I feel like a complete idiot. I've taken up to Calc 2, so I'm not an idiot just been a while.

I have the problem..

$$(n-1)^2 - \frac {(n-2)(n-1)}{2}$$

The answer is..

$$\frac {(n-1)n}{2}$$

How do I get there??

$$2\frac {(n-1)(n-1)}2 - \frac {(n-2)(n-1)}2 \dots$$

I'm so lost..

Comment: Hint:  factor out $(n-1)$ from both terms.

Comment: See.. I tried that and ended up getting n/2.. Are my order of operation messed up?

Comment: @lulu could you help me out? Trying to figure out a bigger problem, need to understand this portion first

Comment: Is the posted solution clear?

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close; the step you are missing is:

$$2\frac{(n-1)(n-1)}{2}-\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}=\frac{(n-1)[2(n-1)-(n-2)]}{2}=\frac{(n-1)[2n-2-n+2]}{2}=\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks, I feel dumb now lol

Comment: Easy to forget the basic tricks, don't worry about it. (But do practice!)